# ¿Cómo regresar al Activity Anterior en Android?

Tags: android

Tengo un activity **B** pero quisiera que cuando presiono un botón me devuelva al activity **A**.
Lo intenté con un **Intent**, pero el problema es que con esto se vuelve a cargar el activity **A** y se pierden los valores que están en los **EditText**.

Comment: solo usa finish(); en la activity b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si abriste Activity B de A y esta no fue destruida con `finish()`, simplementente ejecuta `finish()` en B para regresar a activity A.

Al regresar de esta forma a Activity A no se volvera a construir la Activity, es decir no entraría por el método `onCreate()`, por lo tanto los valores de tus `EditText` permanecerían intactos.

Answer (score 1):

Este tema tiene relacion con StateChange y sus 2 metodos

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
  Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState")
  //********* acá creas una variable y guardas lo que esta en el EditText
  val userText = editText.text
  outState?.putCharSequence("savedText", userText)
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState) 
    //********* para restaurar los valores cuando regreses a la actividad
    val userText = savedInstanceState?.getCharSequence("savedText")
    editText.setText(userText)
    Log.i(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState")
}
```

todo esto va en la actividad A, así cuando presiones o te muevas a la actividad B y quieras regresar a la Actividad A, restaurara los valores que guardaste con los métodos mencionados.

esto es código kotlin, muy parecido a java así que podes traducirlo con facilidad, espero te ayude. 
Saludos